# Unity import atlas with some rotated elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a sprite atlas with number images from 1 to 10 but 7 and 8 are rotated horizontally. How i can import them normally in unity. Cant find answer other places, documentation are have only how to pack sprites with rotation and tight settings.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if I fully understand your problem. Why are you not rotate the image in Windows explorer ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Why not import sprites as individual (non-rotated) images and let Unity pack them into an atlas through [Sprite Atlas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteAtlas.html)?

Or better yet, use a font with TextMeshPro? You can pack only the numeric glyphs if desired.

Alternatively, you would have to manually un-rotate the image every time you're using the rotated sprite from the texture, which is more trouble than the alternatives.